# zabbix configuration with rails and nginx server

Tags: php, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, zabbix

Am running rails on nginx server in production. I want to use zabbix to monitor my server. Anybody with a working nginx configuration of zabbix. I have found these https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=40612  https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=40564 but i have become confused and they are not working.

Comment: You're looking for a PHP setup for nginx.

Comment: will that have any effect on my rails app?

Comment: If you do it right, it will not. Add a new vhost to nginx, which has a php upstream - this will make zabbix available under a different hostname

Comment: I have tried as u have told me. actually I have done it in a similar way shown by the two links i have show above,but it doesnt work. so am looking for a current working example, so that i can modify. Even so, I really appreciate your willingness to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write this Article, maybe it help u!

https://www.zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/howto/high_availability_Zabbix_Frontend

Comment: Thanks, Its a plus article

Answer (score 0):

To install and run zabbix PHP frontend under nginx you need to:

1. Install php-fpm:

   yum|apt-get|whatever php-fpm

there can be php components the frontend depends on, but I don't remember which ones. See [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/installation/requirements).

1. Add a separate server configuration to nginx with fastcgi to php-fpm:

   server {

   ```
   server_name  zabbix.your.domain.com;

   access_log  /home/tlpls/prtp/logs/access.log  main;
   #IMPORTANT: this is where you look for errors and such
   error_log  /home/tlpls/prtp/logs/error.log debug;

   #this is for the static files
   #should point to where your zabbix frontend files are
   location / {
       root   /usr/share/zabbix;
       index  index.php index.html index.htm;
   }
   #and this is what to do with php files
   #same paths probably
   location ~ \.php$ {
       root           /usr/share/zabbix;
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/zabbix$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        fastcgi_params;
   }
   ```

   }

True story ^^^^^^

1. Start php-fpm (/etc/init.d/php-fpm start or something) and reload nginx (nginx -s reload or something)

There you go, can't be more complete of a howto, as @StephenKing already said in the comments, it is just a PHP application for which there are tons of explanations how to setup under nginx including the official nginx documentation.